# How to run command with sudo in perl

Tags: perl, aws-cli

I have below code and aws command only work with sudo

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $ogg_file = '20191220-104756_4301_1571528872-480639.ogg';


    unless (system  ('aws', 's3','cp', $ogg_file, "s3://recordings")==0) {
            print STDERR "Failed to upload   '$ogg_file': $!\n";
           next;
    }
```

I tried to run with sudo but its not working. Can anyone suggest me a better way

Comment: The superuser flag gets passed down to child processes, doesn't it? So you can just `sudo` your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
system  ('aws', 's3','cp', $ogg_file, "s3://recordings")
```

...into one of these:

```
system(qq(sudo aws s3 cp "$ogg_file" "s3://recordings"))
system("sudo aws s3 cp '$ogg_file' s3://recordings")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do following for better readability

```
my $cmd = 'sudo aws s3 ';
$cmd .= 'cp $ogg_file ';
$cmd .= 's3://recordings';
system($cmd);
```